# Warning using exact_extract in R

Tags: r, exact-extract

I have a grid cell shapefile of Africa of 55 km x 55 km.

I would like to calculate a weighted average of the Terrain Ruggedness Index (explain here https://diegopuga.org/data/rugged/#grid) using as a weights the values of the area of each cell. To do that, I have two rasters, one with the Terrain Ruggedness Index, and another with the area of each cell. Both of them have a resolution of 30 by 30 arcsecond. As the authors of the link explained, it's important to take into account that the sea-level surface varies in proportion to the cosine of its latitude, this is why I weights by the area of the cell.

I use the following code:

```
library(raster)
library(sf)
library(exactextractr)


shape$ruggedness = exact_extract(tri, shape, fun = "weighted_mean", weights = cells)
```

where shape is my grid cell, and tri and cells are the raster data of the ruggedness index and area of the cell respectively. These two rasters cover all the world, while my shapefile just Africa.

When I run the code, the following appears: *"Cannot preload entire working area of 109568941 cells with max_cells_in_memory = 3e+07. Raster values will be read for each feature individually."*

I do not understand why that is produced and if this can affect my results.

Comment: It does not affect your results. It means that the calculation is slower than it might be if allowed to use more memory.

Comment: Thank you @dbaston. Is it correct my code according to what I would like to obtain? It's my first time using exact_extract. I would need to use more.

Comment: Looks OK to me.

Comment: @dbaston Thank you!

Comment: I have encountered the same issue and I think it is because the shapefile has too many vertices.

Comment: Nope, not at all. It is due to the default settings of the package limiting the number of raster cells into memory. You can change this default using the `max_cells_in_memory` argument. However, if do not have enough RAM it won't matter. All that happens when this is triggered is that the processing is parsed into manageable chunks, which slows things down. A clear illustration would be if you had a raster w/ 1B cells and tried to use a polygon of the entire extent. You would have to change the default behavior to allow the problem to process in RAM.